# .apk package installation fails on Android

Tags: android

I made an application for Android and I wanted to install the application on my Android (Micromax a60) mobile, so I made the .apk package of application and saved it on a SD card, but when I tap on the .apk package the installation fails. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just copying the apk on the sd card. This will not work. You can install the app on device directly. Connect the device to the system. Enable USB debugging. In Run Configuration, choose target as manual. and then run the project. You will be prompted to choose device. Select the device and the app will be installed on your device. Hope this helps.

Comment: For HTC evo 4g it is, Settings->Applications->Development[USB Debugging]. It should be something similar in your case.